# Moment.js - I'm parsing date but it still complains

Tags: javascript, momentjs

`Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments: [object Object]`

As far as I can tell, I am parsing the date according to the parse docs.

Any suggestions?

```
function graphTitleGenerator(data) {
  var formats = {
    sameDay: '[Today]',
    nextDay: '[Tomorrow]',
    nextWeek: 'dddd',
    lastDay: '[Yesterday]',
    lastWeek: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    sameElse: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
  }
  var today = new Date();
  var refDate =  (today.getMonth()+1) + '-' + today.getDate()
    + '-' + today.getFullYear();
  var graphTitle = moment(data.date, 'MM-DD-YYYY').calendar(refDate, formats);
  return graphTitle;
}
```

Comment: `moment().calendar(refDate, formats)` should work fine. moment() defaults to today's date.

Comment: There does not seem to be any `moment(Date, String)` or `moment(Object, String)` variants.  Perhaps you mean `moment(refDate, 'MM-DD-YYYY').calendar(refDate, formats);`

Comment: I think it is format problem, MM accepts 01 and you passing 1, same with DD

Answer (score 1):

Try the format - 'M-D-YYYY' as the month and date are single digits and you are not prefixing 0.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that `refDate` becomes: `'9-4-2016'` and that is not a known format. Hence the call to `.calendar()` throws that error.

So, I would recommend changing your code to:

```
function dateToMDY(date) {
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    return '' + (m <= 9 ? '0' + m : m) + '-' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d) + '-' + y; 
}

function graphTitleGenerator(data) {
  var formats = { 
    sameDay: '[Today]',
    nextDay: '[Tomorrow]',
    nextWeek: 'dddd',
    lastDay: '[Yesterday]',
    lastWeek: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    sameElse: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
  }
  var today = new Date();
  var refDate = dateToMDY(today);
  var graphTitle = moment(data.date, 'MM-DD-YYYY').calendar(refDate, formats);
  return graphTitle;
}
```

Comment: nice `return`! moment.js is still complaining with `09-04-2016` and `'MM-DD-YYYY'`

Answer (score 1):

When you call calendar, it will accept a moment object for refDate. Since the moment you appear to want is simply one month from today, your code can be written as follows:

```
function graphTitleGenerator(data) {
  var formats = { 
    sameDay: '[Today]',
    nextDay: '[Tomorrow]',
    nextWeek: 'dddd',
    lastDay: '[Yesterday]',
    lastWeek: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    sameElse: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
  }

  var graphTitle = moment(data.date, 'MM-DD-YYYY').calendar(moment().add(1, month), formats);
  return graphTitle;
}
```